# Convert Flat JSON string into hierarchical using Parent ID

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am implementing a Mat-Tree using Angular Material. I have a flat JSON string like:

```
"Entity": [
  {
      "ID": 1,
      "NAME": "Reports",
      "PARENTID": "0",
      "ISACTIVE": "Y",
      "CREATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:08:11",
      "UPDATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:08:11",
      "CREATEDBY": 596241,
      "UPDATEDBY": 596241
  },
  {
      "ID": 2,
      "NAME": "TMS - Reports",
      "PARENTID": 1,
      "ISACTIVE": "Y",
      "CREATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:08:38",
      "UPDATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:08:38",
      "CREATEDBY": 596241,
      "UPDATEDBY": 596241
  },
  {
      "ID": 3,
      "NAME": "TMS - Beneficiary ",
      "PARENTID": 2,
      "ISACTIVE": "Y",
      "CREATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:09:34",
      "UPDATIONDATE": "2020-03-31T15:09:34",
      "CREATEDBY": 596241,
      "UPDATEDBY": 596241
  }
]
```

And I need to convert it into Key-value pairs based on their Parent ID. Something like:

```
{
    Reports: 
    {
      'Type 1 Reports': ['Beneficiary Reports', 'Some Other Report'],
      'Type 2 Reports': null //No Children,
    },

    Some Other Menu Items: {
     'My Parent Node': null,
      'Some Other Menu Node': ['Child 1', 'Child 2']
   } 

}
```

So far, I am able to use this code to convert it into a parent-child hierarchy, but It has pushed all children into Items array which I cannot iterate with Mat-Tree. I need to get rid of the Items and have something like a key-value pair as the one I mentioned above:

```
    generateTreeData(menuResponse)
    { 

    var map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < menuResponse.length; i++){
      var obj = menuResponse[i];
      var parent = '';
      obj.items= [];
      map[obj.ID] = obj;
      if(obj.PARENTID  == "0")
      {
        parent = '-';
      }
      else
      {
        parent = obj.PARENTID;
      }
      if(!map[parent]){
        //Means Parent doesnt exist i.e. node Itself is parent node
          map[parent] = {
             items: []         
            };
      }
       map[parent].items.push(obj);  
    }
    return map['-'].items;
  }
```

**Problem:**

The code puts children nodes in Items array. I need to get rid of the Items array and place it in key-value pairs like the one I mentioned above. How do I just extract the "NAME" and Items out of this JSON array and make a Key-Value pair? Something like the one I mentioned above?

Comment: by reading it I could not understand what should be structure of output. Can you please explain in more detail ?

Comment: @piyushjain this:

Comment: {
    Reports: 
    {
      'Type 1 Reports': ['Beneficiary Reports', 'Some Other Report'],
      'Type 2 Reports': null //No Children,
    },

    Some Other Menu Items: {
     'My Parent Node': null,
      'Some Other Menu Node': ['Child 1', 'Child 2']
   } 

}

Answer (score 0):

The expected output structure doesn't seem right. What if there is a child for 'Beneficiary Reports' node.

The output structure for the input provided in the question should be like:

```
{
   "Reports":[
      {
         "TMS - Reports":[
            {
               "TMS - Beneficiary ":[]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Check the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abby_7700/apkgeo1d/3/

```
var data = [];//your response goes here
var result = {};
var root = data.find(x => x.PARENTID == 0);
result[root.NAME] = [];

findAndAddChildren(root.ID, result[root.NAME]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

function findAndAddChildren(parentID, collection) {
    var rootChildren = data.filter(x => x.PARENTID == parentID);
    for(var i = 0; i < rootChildren.length; i++) {
    var child = rootChildren[i];
    var temp = {};
    temp[child.NAME] = [];
    collection.push(temp);
    findAndAddChildren(child.ID, temp[child.NAME]);
    }
}
```